# How do I use data-testid attribute with a React Component Test?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-typescript, cypress-component-test-runner

I am doing a Component Test on a simple react component, which I want to render and then do some tests on.

The problem is that `cy.get()` does not seem to find the component based on a `data-testid` attribute.

I tested it with a simple `div` and the `div` can be found just fine.

I also noticed when inspecting the `DOM` in the cypress runner, that the Component is not being rendered, but the contents of it are. Basically there is no `<MockComponent>`

```js
  it.only("renders and finds Component", () => {
    cy.mount(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <MockComponent data-testid='mock-component' {...someData} />
        <div data-testid='my-div'></div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );

    cy.get("[data-testid='my-div']").should('exist'); //this works
    cy.get("[data-testid='mock-component']").should('exist'); //this doesn't

  });
```

How can I get the `<MockComponent>` in cypress, so that I can run tests on it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add data-id attributes directly to the the React component and have it appear on the DOM content.

All attributes (data or otherwise) that you put on `MockComponent` are passed in as props to your component. This is standard for React.

So, if you examine `props` inside `MockComponent`, it will have a property named `data-testid` with a value of `mock-component`.

You will have to convert that into an attribute inside `MockComponent`, on one of it's rendered elements.

Note that `MockComponent` never appear in the DOM, just it's rendered children.

For example, explicitly:

```
const MockComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div data-testid={props["data-testid"]}>    
      <span>this is mock component</span>
    </div>
  )
}

...

cy.get("[data-testid='mock-component']")   // passes
```

The `<div>` inside MockComponent's return value is the "outer" element rendered to DOM, so that's where you need the data-id.

---

Or you can do it implicitly. Since `someData` is part of your component API, you can split it off and assume the remainder will be utilized as attributes (without actually knowing what they are).

```js
const MockComponent = (props) => {
  const {someData, ...rest} = props;

  const [data, setData] = useState(someData);

  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <span>this is mock component</span>
    </div>
  )
}

...

cy.get("[data-testid='mock-component']")   // passes
```

---

One more way is to add a child to `MockComponent`, which must be a real element.

All child elements are passed as `props.children`, and you must render them inside the return value.

```js
const MockComponent = (props) => {
  const {someData} = props

  const [data, setData] = useState(someData);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>this is mock component</span>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

...

cy.mount(
  <MockComponent {...someData} >
    <span data-testid='mock-component-child' ></span>
  </MockComponent>
);

cy.get("[data-testid='mock-component-child']")   // passes
  .parent()                              // outer element of MockComponent
```