# cypress-file-upload test the upload functionality with a button inside dropzone component

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-dropzone, cypress-file-upload

I am using react-dropzone library to handle uploading image files. Now I would like to test this upload behaviour. The tests are written using cypress and I am using cypress-file-upload. Here's my component

I tried to follow this example (https://gist.github.com/ZwaarContrast/00101934954980bcaa4ae70ac9930c60) as well, but didn't get it to work .

```
    <ReactDropzone
      onDrop={onDrop}
      multiple={false}
      noDrag
      data-cy="uploadFile"
    >
      <button className={styles.avatarButton}>
        Upload Profile Picture
      </button>
    </ReactDropzone>
```

```
function onDrop(event) {
  const file = event[0];
  //openModal;
}
```

In my test I'm trying to test if the modal opens up, but the modal doesn't open up in my case.

```
  cy.fixture('avatar.png', 'base64').then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('[data-cy="uploadFile"]').attachFile({
     fileContent: fileContent,
     fileName: 'avatar.png',
    });
  });   
  cy.get('[data-cy="uploadFile"]')
  .find('input').trigger('change', {force:true})  
  });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I don't see any modal on file upload. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Cypress Component Test does not render react Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75660579/20728603)

> You can't add data-id attributes directly to the the React component and have it appear on the DOM content.

so `<ReactDropzone ... data-cy="uploadFile">` does not work.

Try instead adding `data-cy="uploadFile"` to the inner element (in your snippet it's `<button>`)

I'm not sure of the exact React code you have, since the piece you show does not run, but to get the `<input>` element you can use [Cypress .closest()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/closest) query to find the associated input.

```js
cy.fixture('avatar.png', 'base64').then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('[data-cy="uploadFile"]')
   .closest('input')                // nearest input to <button>
   .attachFile({
      fileContent: fileContent,
      fileName: 'avatar.png',
    });
  });   
  cy.get('[data-cy="uploadFile"]')
    .find('input').trigger('change', {force:true})  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `.attachFile` with a drag'n'drop component, you have to specify it as the `subjectType`.
[From the docs:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload#drag-n-drop-component)

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]')
  .attachFile('myfixture.json', { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' });
```

In your specific case, it would just be adding the additional options object.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="uploadFile"]').attachFile({
     fileContent: fileContent,
     fileName: 'avatar.png',
    }, { 
     subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' 
    });
  });
```